# java.lang.ClassNotFound - Error inflating custom class

Tags: android, xml, button, include, package

I just want a class, which inherits from "android.widget.Button" and use this instead of the normal Button.
When i inflate the Custom Button, the system can't find the class..
My package:

```
com.kahl.test
```

Here's my Main.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<com.kahl.test.test.MyButton
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
</LinearLayout>
```

the MyButton.cs:

```
namespace test {
    public class MyButton : Button{

        public MyButton (Context context)
        :base (context){
             Initialize ();
        }

        public MyButton (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) 
        :base (context, attrs){
            Initialize ();
        }

        public MyButton (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) 
        :base (context, attrs, defStyle){
            Initialize ();
        }

        void Initialize (){
        }
    }
}
```

and the MainActivity:

```
namespace test{
[Activity (Label = "test", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity{
        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle){
            base.OnCreate (bundle);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            test.MyButton button = FindViewById<test.MyButton>(Resource.Id.myButton);

            button.Click += delegate {
                button.Text = string.Format ("{0} clicks!", count++);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

logcat:

```
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
[MonoDroid] Android.Views.InflateException: Exception of type     'Android.Views.InflateException' was thrown.
[MonoDroid] at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw     () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1978/f98871a9/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runt    ime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:61
[MonoDroid] at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod     (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue*) [0x00084] in     /Users/builder/data/lanes/1978/f98871a9/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Ru    ntime/JNIEnv.g.cs:1029
[MonoDroid] at Android.App.Activity.SetContentView (int) [0x00070] in     /Users/builder/data/lanes/1978/f98871a9/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platfo    rms/android-19/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:4879
[MonoDroid] at test.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x00016] in     c:\Users\Kahlei\Desktop\test\test\MainActivity.cs:22
[MonoDroid] at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_     (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00011] in     /Users/builder/data/lanes/1978/f98871a9/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platfo    rms/android-19/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2475
[MonoDroid] at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.d7001677-56ac-4bd2-97b5-    7a496a39e428 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00017, 0x00027>
[MonoDroid]   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
[MonoDroid] android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error     inflating class com.kahl.test.test.MyButton
[MonoDroid]     at      android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
[MonoDroid]     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290) 
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
[MonoDroid]     at md56996cb2aea8f756b255ad7a6f28adcb8.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
[MonoDroid]     at md56996cb2aea8f756b255ad7a6f28adcb8.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
[MonoDroid]     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
[MonoDroid]     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
[MonoDroid]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
[MonoDroid]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
[MonoDroid]     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
[MonoDroid]     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
[MonoDroid]     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
[MonoDroid] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.kahl.test.test.MyButton" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.kahl.test-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.kahl.test-2, /system/lib]]
[MonoDroid]     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
[MonoDroid]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
[MonoDroid]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
[MonoDroid]     ... 22 more
[AndroidRuntime] Shutting down VM
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, com.kahl.test should be the namespace, not be the application's package name.